# Convert shp 2 sqlite with correct character encoding

Tags: qgis, sqlite

I want to convert Shape data with the QGIS browser in the SQLite database . Unfortunately, the umlauts then appear with a mark (see screen shot ) . I do not want to change the UTF-8 encoding for each Layer .
Can someone help me ?

[image]

Comment: Does the shapefile attribute table look ok, and is the encoding of the shapefile layer set to `System`or to `UTF-8`?

Comment: Shape is okay . The layers are set with system .

Comment: It looks like UTF-8 does not support the character. I would use something like LATIN1 for the encoding. This could be exported with ogr2ogr is that was a suitable option, and the encoding could be set for the session.

Answer (score 2):

If you export the data using `Save As ...`, you can change the encoding to `UTF-8`.

According to my answer for [Incorrect display of national characters from Spatialite in QGIS, Windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108132/incorrect-display-of-national-characters-from-spatialite-in-qgis-windows), there are two ways of loading spatialite data into QGIS, which set the encoding on reading differently. You can try both and see which one works for you.

This bug may be related: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10944